# remove given number of characters from given position in string C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to remove a given number of characters from string and also it must be removed from certain position. Eg. I have a string "helloStackOverFlow" and given numbers: position `i = 5`, numbers of chars to remove `n = 9`. So we get "helloFlow".

When I execute the program, I get error `Unhandled exception at 0x00EC166F in skuska trening.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00EC58D7.`

Here is my code, I think there is a problem with string allocation, it wants to write somewhere what does not exist, but I am not sure...

```
 void remove(char s[], int n, int i){

    int j,dlzka=0;
    dlzka = strlen(s);

    for(j=i; j<dlzka; j++){
        do{
        s[j] = s[j+n];
        }while( (j+n)==dlzka);
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);

}

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    int n, i;

    remove("helloStackOverFlow", 9, 5);

    system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your code

1. You are trying to alter a string literal in

   ```
   remove("helloStackOverFlow", 9, 5);
   ```
2. Your function name, is the same of a that of a standard functio.
3. Your `remove()` function algorithm is wrong, the while loop will never end because neither `j` or `n` are changing inside the loop.

This code should work

```
void removeChunk(char s[], unsigned int n, unsigned int i)
{
    unsigned int k;
    unsigned int length;

    if ((s == NULL) || (i == 0))
        return;
    length = strlen(s);
    if (i + n > length)
        n = length - i;
    for (k = 0 ; (k < n) && (s[k + i - 1] != '\0') ; k++)
        s[k + i] = s[k + i + n];
}

int main()
{
    char s[100] = "helloStackOverFlow";

    removeChunk(s, 9, 5);

    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your example, 9 characters will be moved (18-9), when only 4 need to be (not counting the terminating NULL).

Comment: Maybe `memmove(s+i, s+n+i, strlen(s+n+i)+1);` provided that `s+n+i` is definitely before the terminating nul.

Comment: thank you for that but could you provide some code without using memmove? Thats what I am trying to achieve right now. Thank you :)

Comment: @user3294564 is this what you want?

Comment: Your new (no `memmove()`) code still copies additional chars from beyond the end of the string...

Comment: ..and now it doesn't copy enough if `n` is less than the remaining part of the string.  I think you're trying to copy `n` characters, but you actually need to copy `length - i - n` plus the nul (ie. whatever is left in the string after the removed segment).